# VBA excel 2007. Create Button in cell

Tags: excel, vba, button

I'm creating a button with code

```
Set CreateButton = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add _
                (C.Left, C.Top, C.Width, C.Height)
```

where C is Cell object. Button appears not in cell but little upper.

CreateButton.Top is 107.25. And when I try to assign CreateButton.Top to itself, value is 114.75. What is going on?

Comment: Can you provide any more details?  I wasn't able to re-create your issue with the code you provided.

Comment: I have page layout view mode

Comment: And yes. In normal view mode works fine

Comment: I am using Excel 2013 and I _am_ able to reproduce this

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be related to the margins.  I changed it around and got the button to move its relative position by changing the top margin.  Like you it only happened when adding the button while in page layout mode.  In normal mode everything worked regardless of the margin.

You may be able to compensate with that information.

Comment: Thanks. I solved problem with switching to normal view.  `code` CurrentView = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView. Then I place the button and `code`ActiveWindow.View = CurrentView